# How do I 'zip' two variables together from an array before pushing a function to the console and then rinse and repeat?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The current code Im working with is this:

```
document.getElementById('hexa').className='transtart burna';
document.getElementById('hexb').className='transtart burnb';
document.getElementById('hexc').className='transtart burnc';
document.getElementById('hexd').className='transtart burnd';
document.getElementById('hexe').className='transtart burne';
document.getElementById('hexf').className='transtart burnf';
document.getElementById('hexg').className='transtart burng';
document.getElementById('hexh').className='transtart burnh';
document.getElementById('hexi').className='transtart burni';
document.getElementById('hexj').className='transtart burnj';
document.getElementById('hexk').className='transtart burnk';
document.getElementById('hexl').className='transtart burnl';
document.getElementById('hexm').className='transtart burnm';
```

What Im trying to do is turn it into this:

```
function hexLoad(){
    var hexArray = ["hexa", "hexb", "hexc", "hexd", "hexe", "hexf", "hexg", "hexh", "hexi", "hexj", "hexk", "hexl", "hexm"];
    var burnArray = ["burna", "burnb", "burnc", "burnd", "burne", "burnf", "burng", "burnh", "burni", "burnj", "burnk", "burnl", "burnm"];
    for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length; i++){
         document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).className='transtart ' + burnArray[i]};
    };
 };
```

My conundrum is, the only feasible reason this would work would be because the number of strings in hexArray is the same number of strings in burnArray. Is there another way I can implement a SECOND for loop as an 'array reader' so that I can output the same kind of thing but when the two arrays have different numbers of strings contained in them? **Pretty much what I need to do is ZIP two variables selected from an array into a function and then push that function to the console, and then rinse and repeat.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one loop, you just need to specify the correct condition:

```
for(var i=0; i < hexArray.length && i < burnArray.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).className='transtart ' + burnArray[i];
};
```

Or alternatively:

```
var minLength = Math.min(hexArray.length, burnArray.length);
for(var i=0; i < minLength; i++){
    document.getElementById(hexArray[i]).className='transtart ' + burnArray[i];
};
```

You can implement this in a method like this (note the return value isn't necessary in this case, I just included it for completeness):

```
function zip(a, b, f) {
    var minLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length), result = new Array(1);
    for(var i=0; i < minLength; i++){
        result[i] = f(a[i], b[i], i);
    };
    return result;
}
...

zip(hexArray, burnArray, function(x, y) { 
    document.getElementById(x).className = 'transtart ' + y;
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/EU2qZ/)

Comment: Awesome thank you. You just reminded me why I come to StackOverflow for clear concise answers vs browsing reddit. I swear I had to explain the same thing 5 different ways.